# Pandas to add new column to indicate if the row fits multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A simple dataframe that I want to use the "df.loc" way to add a new column (green) to indicate if the row fits the condition, like:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

csvfile_now = StringIO(
"""
Name    A   B   C   D
Mike    5   11  50  10
Kate    60  9   20  19
Jane    11  14  20  12
""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile_now, sep = '\t', engine='python')
```

I've tried:

```
df_new = df.loc[(df['B'] > (df['A'] * 0.5)) & (df['D'] > (df['C'] * 0.5)), 'Ind'] = 'Yes'
```

Also tried:

```
df['Ind'] = df.loc[:,(df['B'] > (df['A'] * 0.5)) & (df['D'] > (df['C'] * 0.5))]
```

Neither of them worked.

What's the good way to do so?

Comment: Maybe `df.loc[(df['B'] > (df['A'] * 0.5)) & (df['C'] > (df['D'] * 0.5)), 'Ind'] = 'Yes'`? But the result is different from your output.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, thanks! I just didn't realize the it doesn't require "df = df.loc[....". Would you post an answer so that we can close this question, or it'd better I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if df[df[column]>=condition].all:
    df[new_column]=values
```

example

```
if df[df["price"]>=1].all:
    df["hu"]=df["location"]
```